# Ruby: How to get a class based on class name and how can I get object's field based on field name?

Tags: ruby

**Question 1**

How to get a class given a class name as a string ?

For example, say `Product` class has `do_something` method:

```
str = "product"
<what should be here based on str?>.do_something
```

**Question 2**

How to get object's field given a field name as a string ?

For example, say `Product` class has `price` field:

```
str = "price"
product = Product.new
product.<what should be here based on str?> = 1200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `capitalize` and `constantize`:

   ```
   str.capitalize.constantize.do_something
   ```
2. Use `send`:

   ```
   product.send(str + '=', 1200)
   ```

Comment: `constantize` is not standard Ruby though, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

Comment: Use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead of `send` whenever possible to avoid bypassing method visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Jacob's answer to the first question assumes that you're using Rails and will work fine if you are. In case you're not you can call `Kernel::const_get(str)` to find an existing constant by name.

`send` is a pure ruby. There's no need to intern your strings with `send` though (convert them to symbols), straight strings work fine.